# Can't play any video format with VideoView

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-videoview

I hope someone can help me. I have a problem with playing video. I can't play any video format. I have a fragment that looks like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/video"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And the following code inside my fragment activity:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    MediaController media_Controller = new MediaController(getActivity());
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_video, parent, false);
    final VideoView videoView = (VideoView)v.findViewById(R.id.video);
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource//" + getActivity().getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.videofile);
    videoView.setMediaController(media_Controller);
    videoView.setVideoURI(uri);
    videoView.start();

    return v; 
}
```

For every file I application throws me the following message:

```
Sorry, this video cannot be played.
```

These are messages inside my logs:

```
03-26 14:48:10.024: D/OpenGLRenderer(2226): Flushing caches (mode 0)
03-26 14:48:10.034: E/MediaPlayer(2226): error (1, -2147483648)
03-26 14:48:10.054: E/MediaPlayer(2226): Error (1,-2147483648)
03-26 14:48:10.054: D/VideoView(2226): Error: 1,-2147483648
```

**EDIT1:**

Ok, I found a problem. The problem is in this line:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource//" + getActivity().getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.videofile);
videoView.setVideoURI(uri);
```

It doesn't get a correct resource so file cannot be played. The hardcoded solution works:

```
videoView.setVideoPath("android.resource://my.package.name/raw/videofile");
```

I don't understand what is the difference between these two.

Comment: what formats and encoding are you trying to use?

Comment: @FoamyGuy, I tried to use mpg, mp4, 3gp ...

Comment: are you certain that your media files aren't corrupted? Do they play correctly on other devices?

Comment: Yes, that is the file which many people confirmed it's working.

Comment: Can you say us if your videos wheight 0Bytes? That's often a reason for that Error message.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to play internal resource in VideoView. Unfortunately VideoView is an external component and it does not have access to your application data. [Here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=10197#makechanges) yoy got an alternative implementation of VideoView that can handle internal resources

Comment: Thank you for suggestion. Can you check my edit? Why does it work like that?